# Multiple substitutions with a single regular expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Say I have the following in perl:

```
my $string;
$string =~ s/ /\\ /g;
$string =~ s/'/\\'/g;
$string =~ s/`/\\`/g;
```

Can the above substitutions be performed with a single combined regular expression instead of 3 separate ones?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$string =~ s/([ '`])/\\$1/g;
```

Uses a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `` [ '`] `` to match one of space, ' or ` and uses brackets `()` to remember the matched character. `$1` is then used to include the remembered character in the replacement.

Answer (score 4):

Separate substitutions may be much more efficient than a single complex one (e.g. when working with fixed substrings). In such cases you can make the code shorter, like this:

```
my $string;    
for ($string) {
    s/ /\\ /g;
    s/'/\\'/g;
    s/`/\\`/g;
}
```

Comment: Or `$string =~ s/($_)/\\$1/g for (q/ /, q/'/, q/\`/);`

Answer (score 2):

Although it's arguably easier to read the way you have it now, you can perform these substitutions at once by using a loop, or combining them in one expression:

```
# loop
$string =~ s/$_/\\$_/g foreach (' ', "'", '`');

# combined
$string =~ s/([ '`])/\\$1/g;
```

By the way, you can make your substitutions a little easier to read by avoiding "leaning toothpick syndrome", as the various regex operators allow you to use a variety of delimiters:

```
$string =~ s{ }{\\ }g;
$string =~ s{'}{\\'}g;
$string =~ s{`}{\\`}g;
```