# Manipulating undefined entries in a list

Tags: string, perl, list

I am trying to manipulate a list (about 50 columns) where I basically want to select some columns (some 7 or 10). However, some of those columns have empty entries. I am guessing something like this is a minimal working example:

```
A    B    C    D    E#note these are 5 tab separated columns
this    that    semething    something more     the end 
this.line    is    very    incomplete    #column E empty
but    this    is    v.very    complete
whereas        this    is    not #column B empty
```

As you can see, the 3rd line is empty in the last position.

**I want to find a way of *efficiently* replacing all empty fields of my interest by a string, say "NA".**

Of course, I could do it in the following way, but it is not very elegant to do this for all the 10 columns that I have in my real data:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $file,"<","$path\\file.txt"; #with correct path

my @selecteddata;my $blankE;my $blankB;
while (<$data>) {
    chomp $_;
    my @line= split "\t";
    if (not defined $line[4]){
    $blankE="NA";
} else {
    $blankE=$line[4];
}
    if (not defined $line[1]){
    $blankB="NA";
} else {
    $blankB=$line[1];
}
    push @selecteddata,"$blankB[0]\t$line[1]\t$line[2]\t$line[3]$line[4]\n";
}
close $data;
```

Alternatively, I can pre-process the file and replace all undefined entries by "NA", but I would like to avoid this.

So the main question is this: **is there a more elegant way to replace blank entries only in the columns that I am interested by some word?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to not ignoring trailing tabs is to specify a negative LIMIT as the 4th argument to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) (kudos ikegami).

[`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) makes light work of setting the "NA" values:

```
while ( <$data> ) {
    chomp;

    my @fields = split /\t/, $_, -1;

    @fields = map { length($_) ? $_ : 'NA' } @fields;  # Transform @fields

    my $updated = join("\t", @fields) . "\n";

    push @selected_data, $updated ;
}
```

In one-liner mode:

```
$ perl -lne 'print join "\t", map { length ? $_ : "NA" } split /\t/, $_, -1' input > output
```

Comment: @ikegami : Thanks for the bullet-proofing

Comment: `-F` and `-a` have no use in one liner; argument for `length` can be omitted.

Comment: @ikegami : Thanks for the bug-fixing :)

Comment: I was say that -F and -a are useful, but the `split` isn't. :) *shrug*

Comment: Alternative: `@fields = map s/^$/NA/r, @fields`

Comment: And to further nitpick, since `@fields` gets overwritten, perhaps foreach instead of map `length($_) or $_ ='NA' for @fields;`

Comment: perhaps `s/^$/NA/r` but `/r` is from 5.14?

Comment: Yep. Or the less aesthetic `map { s/^$/NA/; $_ } @fields;` to cover older versions of Perl

Comment: +1 Because this is beautiful ... I am ashamed but invoke TIMTOWDI  hoping for forgiveness :)

Comment: After posting my "baby perl" I found [this multiple substitution example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140553/multiple-substitutions-with-a-single-regular-expression-in-perl) on SO with contributions from @ether and @Zaid!  ... I'm still doing baby perl but I feel more kindergarten every day ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I would say that using `split` and `join` undoubtedly is the most clear, since you'll likely need to be doing that for other parsing as well.  However, this could be solved using [`look around assertions`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) as well

Basically, the boundary between elements will either be a tab or the end or beginning of a string, so if those conditions are true for both directions, then we have an empty field:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/(?:^|(?<=\t))(?=\t|$)/NA/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
a   b   c   d   e
a   b   c   d   e
a   b       d   e
    b   c   d   e
a   b           
a   b       d   
a               e
```

Outputs:

```
a       b       c       d       e
a       b       c       d       e
a       b       NA      d       e
NA      b       c       d       e
a       b       NA      NA      NA
a       b       NA      d       NA
a       NA      NA      NA      e
```

Turning this into a one liner is trivial, but I will point out that this could be done using `\K` as well saving 2 characters: `s/(?:\t|^)\K(?=\t|$)/NA/g;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if just using a sequence of substitutions looking for tabs that are either preceded/followed by spaces would catch everything but it's quick and easy if you have a lazy brain ;-)

```
 perl -pne 's/\t\t/\tNA\t/;s/\t\s/\tNA/;s/^\t/NA\t/' col_data-undef.txt
```

I'm not sure if in a neater scriptish format it looks less or more yucky :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# read_cols.pl - munge tab separated data with empty "cells"
use strict; 
use warnings;

while (<>){
 s/\t\t/\tNA\t/;
 s/\t\s/\tNA/;
 s/^\t/NA\t/;
 print ;
}
```

Here's the output:

Here's vim buffers of the input and output with tabs as **^I** in red  ;-)

```
./read_cols.pl col_data-undef.txt > col_data-NA.txt
```

[image: Buffers showing tabs]

Is everything in the correct order?  Would it work on 50 columns ?!?

Sometimes lazy is good but sometimes you need @ikegami ... **:-)**

Comment: In my own defense I give you [Exhibit A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3140845/2019415) here on SO where Zaid comments neutrally on similar syntax ;-)

Comment: Just so you know, this code is buggy (in particular the second `s///`).

Comment: @Zaid :-\  oops - thought it worked so I `rm`ed it ... will try again ...  do you mean the code at the link or the list of `s///`'s above?

Comment: What if there is a tab followed by a space? According to the OP's requirements such a field should not be NA-ized.