# Perl regular expression looks incorrect according to syntax highlighting of UltraEdit

Tags: regex, perl, ultraedit

A previous post looks close to what I would like to try: [Multiple Substitutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140553/multiple-substitutions-with-a-single-regular-expression-in-perl)

Here are the substitutions I am trying to make:

```
$description =~ s/\"/\\"/g;
$description =~ s/\n/<br>/g;
```

When I view my `CGI` script using `UltraEdit` it looks to be incorrect. If I comment out the first line `($description =~ s/\"/\\"/g;)` all code looks good.

I don't see what the error is?

Comment: *Only perl can parse Perl.* Don't really expect any syntax highlighting out there to be 100% correct all the time.

Comment: The first double-quote doesn't need to be escaped. But you could use a look-ahead `s/(?=")/\\/g`

Comment: I used Mofi's suggestion: $description =~ s/\"/\\\"/g; which worked great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With active file being a Perl syntax highlighted file as indicated in status bar at bottom of main window of UltraEdit by string **Perl**, open in UltraEdit from main menu **Advanced - Configuration - Editor Display - Syntax Highlighting**.

**Perl** is already selected in list of *Installed wordfiles* (or *Language* in older versions of UltraEdit). Clicking on button **Open** opens the wordfile containing the syntax highlighting definitions for **Perl**. The configuration dialog should be closed with **Cancel**.

The syntax highlighting wordfile for **Perl** installed with UltraEdit v22.0 has as first line:

```
/L5"Perl" PERL_LANG EnableMLS Line Comment = # Line Comment Preceding Chars = [~[^]^^$/\(] Block Comment On = =pod Block Comment Off = =cut Block Comment On Alt = =item Block Comment Off Alt = =cut Escape Char = \ File Extensions = CGI PL PM PLX
```

Important on this syntax highlighting issue are:

1. **EnableMLS**
   which enables multi-line string highlighting as in Perl a string can span over multiple lines.
2. **Escape Char = \**
   which defines the escape character for double and single quotes inside strings.
3. **String Chars = "'**
   not present here resulting in using the internal defaults for characters marking start and end of a string which is a double quote and a single quote.

UltraEdit has no real Perl language intellisense for syntax highlighting. So it does not know that the double quotes on first line of your example block are inside a Perl regular expression and should be therefore completely ignored for string highlighting.

The first double quote in the regular expression is ignored as being escaped with a backslash. But the second double quote is not escaped and therefore syntax highlighting engine of UltraEdit interprets it as start of a string and highlights now everything up to next not escaped double quote as a string.

The second double quote could be also escaped with a backlash to get the syntax highlighting here correct in UltraEdit, i.e.

```perl
$description =~ s/\"/\\\"/g;
```

Whether the first nor the second double quote must be for Perl interpreter escaped in this regular expression. But doing it nevertheless helps to get this line correct highlighted in UltraEdit and most likely most other text editors.

The wordfile for Perl can be closed as nothing can be done in the wordfile regarding this syntax highlighting issue.

I agree with comment written by [Lucas Trzesniewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3764814/lucas-trzesniewski): *Only perl can parse Perl.*

By the way: By adding just a single quote or just a double quote to a color group on a separate line, it would be possible to highlight single quote strings with a different color than double quoted strings. For example appending

```
/C9"Single Quoted Strings"
'
```

results in highlighting single quoted strings with color and font style defined for color group 9 when using UltraEdit >= v17.00 supporting up to 20 color groups whereas double quoted strings are still highlighted with color and font style defined for strings. UltraEdit < v17.00 as well as UEStudio < v11.00 support only up to 8 color groups. More about syntax highlighting definitions can be read on UltraEdit forum page [template for syntax highlighting language wordfile](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4124).

Comment: Thanks Mofi...I updated the perl word file as suggested above but it had no affect. Your other suggestion to add the additional slash did the trick!

Comment: I tested my suggestion with `/C9"..."` and the single quote with UE v22.0.0.58. The alternate highlighting for single quoted strings in comparison to double quoted strings works. Of course the color for color group __Single Quoted Strings__ of language __Perl__ must be also configured either at __View - Themes - Manage Themes__ on tab __Syntax__ (UE >= 20.00) or in __Syntax Highlighting__ configuration dialog (UE < 20.00).

Comment: Unfortunately, as Lucas said above "Only Perl can parse Perl". Once I uploaded the script to my server...it did not parse...I reset back to the original code that looks "incorrect" in UltraEdit and it works fine in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have UltraEdit, but I sometimes encounter the same situation with Emacs perl-mode.  The solution is usually to add a comment with a closing quote character, i.e.:

```
$description =~ s/\"/\\"/g;  # " Satisfy the angry syntax highlighting gremlins
$description =~ s/\n/<br>/g;
```

Your mileage may vary.